# AVPlayer event handling after stall/bufferempty event occured

Tags: ios, streaming, media-player, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer for playing Live video using HLS. I subscribed for all the events and notifications related to AVPlayer, AVPlayerItem.
Due to network or mediaserver delay, video freezes sometimes. In this case, I get AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification or playbackBufferEmpty (But these notifications are not very consistent).
When I get these notifications, I am showing some buffering animations on the screen. But , once the response comes from the server, I am not getting any notification to remove buffering animation.

I subscribed for below notifications
AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification
AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeErrorKey
AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification
AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntryNotification
AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntryNotification
AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification
On AVPlayer: status
On AVPlayerItem : status, playbackBufferEmpty, playbackBufferFull and playbackLikelyToKeepUp

- How to make AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification or playbackBufferEmpty notifications consistent or what changes can be done server side to map HTTP error codes to AVPlayer events?
- How to get notifications when the server gives response?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, how did you solve them? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?